# Pushing items to array in object without knowing the key beforehand

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting a response from a request, and I want to display manipulate the data to be an object with arrays. The response looks like "events/month/event". I want to end up with an object where the each month is a key, and the value is an array of events. I've managed to split up the key and event, but I come short when I want to put it into the object. 
I don't know the keys that are in the response, so I can't define them in the resultObj as arrays. For this reason I can't use push to extend the array.

```
const response = [
  "events/july/",
  "events/july/summer-party",
  "events/july/bbq",
  "events/dec/",
  "events/dec/christmas",
  "events/dec/new-year"
];


let resultObj = {};
response.forEach(item => {
  let str = item;
  let key = str.replace("events/", "");
  let event = key.split("/").pop();

  key = key.substring(0, key.indexOf("/"));
  resultObj[key] = [event];
})

console.log(resultObj);
// july: ["bbq"], dec: ["new-year"]
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3z1de2r4/1/

Comment: Can you try to explain it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split and destructure the key and value and push only if a truthy value is available.

```js
const response = ["events/july/", "events/july/summer-party", "events/july/bbq", "events/dec/", "events/dec/christmas", "events/dec/new-year"];

let resultObj = {};

response.forEach(item => {
    let [, key, value] = item.split("/");
    value && (resultObj[key] = resultObj[key] || []).push(value);
});

console.log(resultObj);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, and a very clean solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```js
const response = [
  "events/july/",
  "events/july/summer-party",
  "events/july/bbq",
  "events/dec/",
  "events/dec/christmas",
  "events/dec/new-year"
];

let eventsByMonth = {};
response.forEach(item => {
  let [, month, event] = item.split('/');
  if (event === '') {
    eventsByMonth[month] = [];
  }
  else {
    eventsByMonth[month].push(event);
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(eventsByMonth));
```

The key point here is extracting the whole dataset by exactly one split operation (using destructuring assignment feature of ES6 as a convenience).

BTW, I'm not sure why do you even need this 'month-only' line in your response (like 'events/july/', 'events/dec/'etc.). If you are able to drop it, you can auto-vivify the month array if necessary:

```
if (!eventsByMonth.hasOwnProperty(month)) {
  eventsByMonth[month] = [];
}
eventsByMonth[month].push(event);
```

... but it's not good now, as you need to check the 'event' string for emptiness anyway.